# Django: Use other model classes as choices for a field

Tags: python, django, oop, django-models

I'm writing a Django app that includes a poll section, and I want to offer the ability to create different types of questions. So, I have these models for the rating part

```
# Do I really need this class?
class BaseRating(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

# For questions like: "Rate your experience with XXXXX"
class FiveStarRating(BaseRating):
    rating = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, validators=[MaxValueValidator(5)])

# For questions like: "Would you recommend XXXXX"?
class YesNoRating(BaseRating):
    rating = models.BooleanField()
```

I now want to create a new question, and I want to specify the rating system for it:

- If I create the question "How would you rate xxxxx", I'd use FiveStarRating model
- If I create the question "Are you satisfied with xxxx", I'd use YesNoRating

So, **how should I design the question model?**

```
class Question(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    # rating??
    # I can't create a foreignkey field to the base class...
```

**EDIT: I am finally using [django-dynamic-forms](https://github.com/MarkusH/django-dynamic-forms), but I consider the first response as an acceptable one too**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i can see, you're not using the `BaseRating` model for anything, so it's safe to remove it.

As for the questions, in my case, i'll create two new models that have foreign keys to both `FiveStarRating` and `YesNoRating` so the data can be exclusive from each other. so you'll end up having two models like this.

```
class FiveStarQuestion(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    rating = fields.ForeignKey(FiveStarRating)

class YesNoQuestion(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    rating = fields.ForeignKey(YesNoRating)
```

but if you want to share the titles among the two questions (I would second this approach because there might be two questions with the same title)

Example:
How would you rate **Stackoverflow**

and

How Satisfied are you with **Stackoverflow**

It makes sense to have only one title called **Stackoverflow** and use that Reference as a foreignkey in our tables. So in this case, you can keep the `Question` model and have `ForiegnKey` fields that point to it.

```
class Question(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

The create the two models as follows:

```
class FiveStarQuestion(models.Model):
    title = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    rating = fields.ForeignKey(FiveStarRating)

class YesNoQuestion(models.Model):
    title = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    rating = fields.ForeignKey(YesNoRating)
```

Comment: Thanks! Trying to fit another requisite in this approach: a model Poll, that contains a manytomany relation to all the questions (because the same poll can have different types of questions and the same question can be in more than one poll). I don't want 2 fields in the Poll model (one for YesNoQuestions and another one for FiveStarQuestion).